# Mapping ActiveRecord attribute to PHP class in Yii2

Tags: php, sql-server, activerecord, yii2, geometry

### Prehistory:

I have Microsoft SQL Server as DBMS behind my Yii2 REST API. SQL Server has its internal data types: `geography` and `geometry`. Techincally, in terms of PDO, these types are PHP binary strings

### Question:

So, i need a transparent way to map columns of these types to my class `MyApp\Geometry`, for example. 
That is i should be able to:

1. access ActiveRecord instance property as `Geometry` instance(e.g `$model->geometryBorders->someGeometryTransformation();`
2. save ActiveRecord instance with `Geometry` property transformation by `__toString()` method

As of the second point - it looks clear for me ( as far, as i understand, PDO engine automatically converts all values to PHP string type before sending them to DBMS), but about the first point - i do not know how to implement it within the Yii2 architecture

So, are there any way to map ActiveRecord attribute to PHP class?
I belive, that someone has already met this problem before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use [`afterFind()`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-baseactiverecord#afterFind()-detail) method or [`afterFind`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-baseactiverecord#EVENT_AFTER_FIND-detail) event to userialize object from DB.

```
public function afterFind() {
    parent::afterFind();
    $this->geometryBordersObject = Geometry::fromString($this->geometryBorders);
}
```

And reverse operation before saving ([`beforeSave()`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-baseactiverecord#beforeSave()-detail) method or [`beforeInsert`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-baseactiverecord#EVENT_BEFORE_INSERT-detail) and [`beforeUpdate`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-baseactiverecord#EVENT_BEFORE_UPDATE-detail) events):

```
public function beforeSave() {
    $this->geometryBorders = $this->geometryBordersObject->toString();

    return parent::beforeSave();
}
```

You may also try using getters and setters to provide virtual attributes, but it may be tricky with object.